# I can't read attributes with namespace (ns2) using JAXB to parse XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, ns2

I have to read data from this XML file:

```
<SENT_112 xmlns:ns2="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/STypes.xsd" xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_112.xsd">
<Carrier><ns2:TraderInfo><ns2:IdSisc>PL957271726800000</ns2:IdSisc><ns2:TraderName>FIRMA SPÓŁKA Z OGRANICZONĄ ODPOWIEDZIALNOŚCIĄ</ns2:TraderName>
<ns2:TraderIdentityType>NIP</ns2:TraderIdentityType>
<ns2:TraderIdentityNumber>9572717268</ns2:TraderIdentityNumber>
</ns2:TraderInfo>
<ns2:TraderAddress><ns2:Street>Arysztacka</ns2:Street><ns2:HouseNumber>91A</ns2:HouseNumber><ns2:City>Cieszyn</ns2:City><ns2:Country>PL</ns2:Country><ns2:PostalCode>43-400</ns2:PostalCode></ns2:TraderAddress></Carrier>
</SENT_112>
```

My main class is using JAXB:

```
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SENT_112.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        SENT_112 sent_112 = (SENT_112) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(sent_112, System.out);
```

Carrier.java

```
public class Carrier implements java.io.Serializable {
     private int nrCarrier;
     //private String sentnumber;
     private String IdSisc;
     private String tradername;
     private String traderidentitytype;
     private String traderidentitynumber;
     private String street;
     private String housenumber;
     private String city;
     private String country;
     private String postalcode;
//Contrutors
//Getters and Setters 
//ToString Method
```

SENT_112.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SENT_112")
public class SENT_112 {
    @XmlElement(name="Carrier")
    private List<Carrier> carrier;
    public List<Carrier> getCarrier() {
        return carrier;
    }
```

PACKAGE-INFO.JAVA

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_112.xsd",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.przedlak.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

And my Code return that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SENT_112 xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_112.xsd">
    <Carrier>
        <nrCarrier>0</nrCarrier>
    </Carrier>
</SENT_112>
```

What is wrong with my Code? I need read all information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all information, write your classes appropriately i.e. to retrieve all data. Change `Carrier.java` to :

**Carrier.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Carrier")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Carrier  implements java.io.Serializable 
{
    @XmlElement( name = "TraderInfo" )
    private TraderInfo traderInfo;

    @XmlElement( name = "TraderAddress" )
    private TraderAddress traderAddress;

    private int nrCarrier;

    public int getNrCarrier() {
        return nrCarrier;
    }

    public void setNrCarrier(int nrCarrier) {
        this.nrCarrier = nrCarrier;
    }

    public TraderInfo getTraderInfo() {
        return traderInfo;
    }

    public void setTraderInfo(TraderInfo traderInfo) {
        this.traderInfo = traderInfo;
    }

    public TraderAddress getTraderAddress() {
        return traderAddress;
    }

    public void setTraderAddress(TraderAddress traderAddress) {
        this.traderAddress = traderAddress;
    }
}
```

Then define two classes for `TraderAddress`, `TraderInfo` as:

**TraderInfo**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TraderInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TraderInfo
{
    @XmlElement( name = "IdSisc")
    private String IdSisc;

    @XmlElement( name = "TraderName")
    private String tradername;

    @XmlElement( name = "TraderIdentityType")
    private String traderidentitytype;

    @XmlElement( name = "TraderIdentityNumber")
    private String traderidentitynumber;

    public String getIdSisc() {
        return IdSisc;
    }

    public void setIdSisc(String idSisc) {
        IdSisc = idSisc;
    }

    public String getTradername() {
        return tradername;
    }

    public void setTradername(String tradername) {
        this.tradername = tradername;
    }

    public String getTraderidentitytype() {
        return traderidentitytype;
    }

    public void setTraderidentitytype(String traderidentitytype) {
        this.traderidentitytype = traderidentitytype;
    }

    public String getTraderidentitynumber() {
        return traderidentitynumber;
    }

    public void setTraderidentitynumber(String traderidentitynumber) {
        this.traderidentitynumber = traderidentitynumber;
    }

}
```

**TraderAddress.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TraderInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TraderAddress
{


    @XmlElement( name = "Street")
    private String street;

    @XmlElement( name = "HouseNumber")
    private String houseNumber;

    @XmlElement( name = "City")
    private String city;

    @XmlElement( name = "Country")
    private String country;

    @XmlElement( name = "PostalCode")
    private String postalCode;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }

    public void setHouseNumber(String houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

}
```

With this setup, you should get full xml from marshalling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SENT_112 xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/SENT/2017/01/18/SENT_112.xsd">
    <Carrier>
        <TraderInfo>
            <IdSisc>PL957271726800000</IdSisc>
            <TraderName>FIRMA SPÃ“Å?KA Z OGRANICZONÄ„ ODPOWIEDZIALNOÅšCIÄ„
            </TraderName>
            <TraderIdentityType>NIP</TraderIdentityType>
            <TraderIdentityNumber>9572717268</TraderIdentityNumber>
        </TraderInfo>
        <TraderAddress>
            <Street>Arysztacka</Street>
            <HouseNumber>91A</HouseNumber>
            <City>Cieszyn</City>
            <Country>PL</Country>
            <PostalCode>43-400</PostalCode>
        </TraderAddress>
        <nrCarrier>0</nrCarrier>
    </Carrier>
</SENT_112>
```

Comment: Why '@XmlRootElement on all classes ? '@XmlAccessorType should be sufficient on classes besides the root one (SENT_112). Also, there is a problem with namespaces : the root and carrier element have different namespaces than the rest of the element, if you do not precise the namespaces, the traderInfo and address element will be null when unmarshalled.

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien the OP has already a package-info.java that has namespace definition.

Comment: Yes, but all the elements do not use this namespace. The package-info reference the xmlns namespace, but traderInfo, for example, use the ns2 namespace. The two namespaces look similar, but actually are different.